# Low Quality Review : Link only Answer option available on the answer

Tags: bug, review, low-quality-posts

I am come through many post where only Link only Answer option available. Sometime its really helpful but in some cases there is no link on the answer and only option of Link Only Answer is available.

Here is [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33638734/2900893).

Here is [review link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13528817).

I have captured the screen shot. Have a look.

[image]

I think there is a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Link-only answers are the only ones that have a predefined comment that still usefully applies to them (per the text at the bottom), and there are a lot of old L-O answers that SE wants to get rid of, especially on Stack Overflow.

It might be *nice* if the auto-comments were a bit more dynamic and didn't show link-only as an option without a link of some variety, but that's not really a bug. And in this case, what would the dialog show? Just a single "No comment needed" option button, the disclaimer, and the Delete/Cancel buttons? Seems wasteful.

Comment: there is no link in the question / comments

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot: I know. See second paragraph.